# Obfuscate a Selenium based software with Proguard

Tags: java, selenium, obfuscation, proguard

I've developped an automated testing software deeply relying on Selenium. 
Now that I need to secure my code I'm clearly regretting that choice, but still.

I've tried to use ProGuard. That's my config file :

```
-injars '...robotBU.jar'
-outjars '...robotOBF.jar'

-libraryjars 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar'
-libraryjars '...selenium-server-standalone-2.28.0.jar'

-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
-dontshrink
-dontoptimize
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-verbose
-dontnote
-dontwarn


-keep class test.**
```

Still, when I execute program I get this :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver
>          at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>          at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
>          at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoa
>   der.java:56)
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver
>          at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
>          at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
>          at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>          at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
>          at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>          at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>          ... 3 more
>
> Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid block type
>          at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
>          at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
>          at sun.misc.Resource.getBytes(Unknown Source)
>          at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
>          at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
>          ... 9 more

Any hint about what may cause this problem?

--- Update

I tried with a different Selenium jar as adviced, but that lead me to this problem in Proguard :

```
  Unexpected error while performing partial evaluation:
  Class       = [test/V14_02_10/TestSaisieFeuilleDeSoinLB]
  Method      = [a()V]
  Exception   = [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException] (Can't find common super class of     [org/openqa/selenium/NoSuchElementException] (with 2 known super classes) and [org/openqa/selenium/WebElement] (with 1 known super classes))
Unexpected error while preverifying:
  Class       = [test/V14_02_10/TestSaisieFeuilleDeSoinLB]
  Method      = [a()V]
  Exception   = [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException] (Can't find common super class of     [org/openqa/selenium/NoSuchElementException] (with 2 known super classes) and     [org/openqa/selenium/WebElement] (with 1 known super classes))
Can't find common super class of [org/openqa/selenium/NoSuchElementException] (with 2     known super classes) and [org/openqa/selenium/WebElement] (with 1 known super classes)
```

Comment: Yes. You're missing the selenium jars. That is `...selenium-server-standalone-2.28.0.jar` is wrong.

Comment: I replaced my path with ..., but in my config file there is the right one.

Comment: Your exception "NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver" says otherwise. It is possible that this "java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid block type at" is saying the jar file is corrupt. Regardless, it's not the right one.